# Link many cells with a VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to link 100 cells together. With excel formular it works like this:

`A2 & " " & B2 & " "` and so on..

[screenshot of excelsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGguO.png)

I want to keep a little space between the cell's content like in the example formular above.

Is there a macro or function to accomplish this easily for that amount of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TEXTJOIN

**Excel**

In Cell `CW1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",FALSE,A1:CV1)
```

Copy down to cell `CW10000`.

**VBA**

Option Explicit

```
Sub tj()
    ' Constants
    Const FirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const NoR As Long = 10000
    Const NoC As Long = 100
    ' Define range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(FirstCell).Resize(NoR, NoC)
    With rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, NoC)
        ' Write formulas.
        .Formula = "=TEXTJOIN("" "",FALSE," & rng.Rows(1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
        ' Write values.
         .Value = .Value
    End With
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data concatenated.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Sub tj2()

   ' Constants
    Const FirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const NoR As Long = 10000
    Const NoC As Long = 100

    ' Define range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(FirstCell).Resize(NoR, NoC)

    ' Write values from range to array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value

    ' Write resulting values to first column of array.
    Dim CurrentValue As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To 10000
        CurrentValue = ""
        For j = 1 To 100
            CurrentValue = CurrentValue & " " & Data(i, j)
        Next j
        Data(i, 1) = Right(CurrentValue, Len(CurrentValue) - 1)
    Next i

    ' Write values from first column of array to column range.
    rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, NoC).Value = Data

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data concatenated.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much, somehow "=TEXTJOIN(" ",FALSE,A1:CV1)" this does not put an empty space between the values

Answer (score 1):

TEXTJOIN is an option, like in @VBasic2008's Answer, unfortunately it is only available in Excel 2019 and 365 (and above, for future readers).
If you are working with earlier versions of excel, you can do it like this.

Put this UDF in a standard VBA Module:

```
Public Function MyTextJoin(rng As Range)
    Dim str As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Value))
    str = Join(arr, " ")
    MyTextJoin = str
End Function
```

and use it on the Worksheet like this: `=MyTextJoin(A1:CV1)`

Comment: hello horst, oh that's maybe the reason :D.  thank you very much horst!!

Comment: *only available in Office 365*: I'm using it in 2019.

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation, i must have missed that [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c). i added 2019 to my answer

Comment: Maybe delimiter could be an optional string parameter of MyTextJoin.